# Why will I get TimeSpan when a DateTime var minus another DateTime var in C#?

Tags: c#

The  Code A is from a sample project, I'm very strange why I will get a `TimeSpan` when a `DateTime` var minus another  `DateTime` var ?

I think  the `DateTime` var will be return when a `DateTime` var minus another `DateTime` var, just like Code B.  You know that Code C is so.

**Code A**

```
                DateTime dt1 = DateTime.FromOADate(lastVisted);
                DateTime dt2 = DateTime.Now;
                TimeSpan difference = dt2 - dt1;
```

**Code B**

```
                DateTime dt1 = DateTime.FromOADate(lastVisted);
                DateTime dt2 = DateTime.Now;
                DateTime difference = dt2 - dt1;
```

**Code C**

```
    int a = 5;
    int b = 4;
    int c = a-b;
```

Comment: The difference between yesterday and today is not `today` or `yesterday` (or any other date), it is `one day`.

Comment: TimeSpan represents a duration of time.

Comment: DateTimes represent a point I'm time, say, noon today (`dt1`) and 8:00 pm last night (`dt2`). The difference between noon today and 8:00 pm last night (`dt2 - dt1`) is 16 hours,   a span of time

Comment: Your expectation makes no sense. Datetimes are represented as floating point values, where the whole part represents the number of days from a base date and the decimal portion represents the time within a  24-hour period. Let's say that Date1 is `01/15/2023` and Date2 is `01/01/2023`. What DateTime value would you expect subtracting them? DId you try it and look at the result? It's not what you would expect - it would be a date from a long time (decades) ago. A TimeSpan represents a duration, which in my example would be 15 days. This is something you could test in about two minutes yourself.

Comment: @KenWhite: Nope, DateTime's are not _"represented as floating point values"_

Comment: A `DateTime` is a point in time. A `TimeSpan` is a period of time. The 'distance' between `dt1` and `dt2` is a span of time, not a point in time.

Comment: @Flydog57: Yes, they are. They have been since C# was first designed. It's also the same in Excel, VBA and VB.Net, and as far back as VB6.

Comment: Tell me then, what `DateTime` value would you expect to get by subtracting yesterday's date from today's date? And don't say "1 day" because that is not a `DateTime`. That is a span of time, a `TimeSpan`.

Comment: Thank you all, I think the Code B is correct just like Code C

Comment: Do you mean C# conevrt  `dt2 - dt1` to `TimeSpan` automatically?

Comment: @KenWhite I think you are confusing DateTimes with OLE Automation Date Times. Read the DateTime docs _"The DateTime value type represents dates and times with values ranging from 00:00:00 (midnight), January 1, 0001 Anno Domini (Common Era) through 11:59:59 P.M., December 31, 9999 A.D. (C.E.) in the Gregorian calendar."_ and _"Time values are measured in 100-nanosecond units called ticks. A particular date is the number of ticks since 12:00 midnight, January 1, 0001 A.D. (C.E.) in the GregorianCalendar calendar"_. I'm about 99% that's maintained in integral values  not float-ish numbers

Comment: Or  DateTime is child class, and TimeSpan is parent class, so a object of child can be assigned to a parent class object, right?

Comment: They are both`struct`s  not `class`es

Comment: @HelloCW This is no parent-child relationship here as DateTime and Timespan are both structs. This a case of operator overloading for DateTime type which is returns TimeSpan after the calculation.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime.op_subtraction?view=net-7.0

Comment: There's no rule saying that an expression involving two values of type X must also be of type X. Subtracting an `int` from an `int` happens to be defined to result in an `int`, and a lot of the built-in operators follow this, but it isn't a rule that all types have to obey.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A [TimeSpan](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.timespan?view=net-7.0) will be returned when subtracting one DateTime from another DateTime as that is how the [subtraction operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime.op_subtraction?view=net-7.0#system-datetime-op-subtraction(system-datetime-system-datetime)) is defined for [DateTime](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime?view=net-7.0).

Comment: Thanks!  Do you mean that DateTime Overloads Subtraction Operator? so I get TimeSpan when  subtracting one DateTime from another DateTime ?